# Sharepoint REST API - Filter by Negative Number

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api, filter, odata

I'm trying to filter by a negative number but it only seems to work with zero or positive.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  My query is below:

```
spUrl + '/SitePages/checklist.aspx?filter=ChecklistID/DueBusinessDay eq -1'
```

I have also tried this to no avail:

```
spUrl + "/SitePages/checklist.aspx?filter=ChecklistID/DueBusinessDay eq '-1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
/SitePages/checklist.aspx?($filter=ChecklistID/DueBusinessDay eq -1)&$expand=ChecklistID
```

My test code:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test4')/items?$select=nun,Owner/ID&($filter=Owner/ID ge -1)&$expand=Owner
```

Owner is a people column.

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Amos.  I do have the expand but it only works with positive or zero. It is really strange.  I also tried encoding the minus sign but it did not work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you add parentheses?

Comment: No I have not.  Do you mean to do this: SitePages/checklist.aspx?($filter=ChecklistID/DueBusinessDay eq (-1))&$expand=ChecklistID

Comment: check the update.

Comment: I did the same but still no success.  Below is my query parameters: /items?$select=Category,ID,ChecklistID/DueBusinessDay&$expand=ChecklistID&$orderby=DueDate%20asc&$filter=Period eq 'JUL-20' and ChecklistID/DueBusinessDay eq -3.  It is strange that it works with only positive and zero as filter value.  The column is a Lookup column.